# Razor - Can I make an optional model for a view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working with MVC3 with Razor for first time, and I have a partial view which is used in many other places and has no model. And now I need it, can I create an optional model? If it is passed, then I'll use it, otherwise I'll leave the default behavior.

[Update]

I'd like to call it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_myPartialView")
```

or this:

```
@Html.Partial("_myPartialView", "Some string")
```

(the partial view model is a string)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@model FooBar
@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>
}
else
{
    <div>No model passed</div>
}
```

---

UPDATE:

After showing the way you are calling your partial, here's what you could do:

```
@Html.Partial("_myPartialView", null, new ViewDataDictionary())
@Html.Partial("_myPartialView", "Some string")
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when no model is passed, ie:

    `@Html.Partial("_myPartialView")`

 _The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ModelOfTheContainerView', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PartialViewModel'._

Comment: @kerzek, I have updated my answer to show you how you could call the partial with a null model without getting this exception. You need to use the 3rd argument and of the helper and pass a new ViewDataDictionary to avoid having the parent model being passed to the partial.

Comment: thanks. You're right, if I call it with two parameters, then take the model of the parent. I think I have no choice, I'll edit all the calls with a string.empty instead.

Comment: Yes, that's how the Html.Partial helper works. It takes the parent model if you don't explicitly specify a different model which is not null.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make this work is to not constrain the type of your model using the `@model` directive. Then you can use your own variables for the different types of models that might get passed in to the partial view (either from being explicitly set in the call to `@Html.Partial` or just inherited from the containing view).

Let's say the users of your website are either employees or customers and you have a little partial view for displaying some info that should work regardless of how they're logged in (or even if they aren't). Your models look something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public string GetPrimaryRole() { /* Fetch the name of the primary Role from Roles */ }
    // A bunch of other stuff...
}

public class Customer
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual int RewardsPoints { get; set; }
    // A bunch of other stuff...
}
```

As you can see, the information is similar, but it would be really difficult to abstract these two things into a common interface. At the top of your partial view, you could put something like this:

```
@{
    var employee = Model as Employee;
    var customer = Model as Customer;
    string message = "Welcome, Guest!"; //This is displayed if they aren't logged in
    if (employee != null)
    {
        message = string.Format("Welcome, {0} {1}, {2}!",
            employee.FirstName, employee.LastName, employee.GetPrimaryRole());
    }
    else if (customer != null)
    {
        message = string.Format("Welcome, {0}! You have {1} points!",
            customer.FullName, customer.RewardsPoints);
    }
}
<div>@message</div>
```

Obviously this is a very simplistic example, but it illustrates how this could be done simply and cleanly. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass null in `@Html.Partial("_myPartialView", null)`

Then you validate the model in the view as Darin suggested.

But the best solution, imo, would be to pass a ViewModel object to your view containing the string property you need. You make it extensible and you don't pass a null in, you pass a new ViewModel object with an empty or null string.

Comment: I've tried, but if I call with the second parameter as null, then the partial take the model of the parent. I need the third parameter, or, int this case, a string.empty.